# Context menu on custom shortcut

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QGraphicsView` in my MainWindow and I have a custom "grab" function on my canvas (which is the `QGraphicsView` inside my MainWindow) called when I press both mouse buttons.

So I want to activate my context menu only when I press CTRL + right click and prevent from activating only with a right click. It would be important to keep `ActionsContextMenu` policy.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you should subclass the mouse event of the canvas to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for [KeyboardModifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum). You can specify which modifier you want. In your case, it is the `ControlModifier`. Then, override the method `mousePressEvent()` :

```
void yourClass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton &&
        event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)
    {
        // call your context menu
    }
}
```

---

If you want to use this, you'll need to call a `QMenu`. Just add this function in your class :

```
void yourClass::showMenu()
{
    QMenu contextMenu(this);

    QAction action("My Action", this);
    contextMenu.addAction(&action);

    contextMenu.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: But how can i call my context menu? For me now it's automatic, i just added actions to it.

Comment: What do you mean it is automatic? Show your code with the menu then

Comment: I have no code for menu. I just changed ContextMenuPolicy to ActionsContextMenu in PropertyEditor and added an Action in ActionEdior. And now when i right click i have a context menu.

Comment: Oh, ok. You can't do this if you want to override `mousePressEvent`. You just need to add a function in which you add a QMenu, in which you add a QAction and then you call `menu.exec()`. Now you can call this function in the `mousePressEvent`

Comment: Please write it as an answer and i'll accept it. I did the same right before you commented :)